# Remove and Merge data with different name in JSON object || Python

Tags: python, json, data-manipulation

all I want to merge duplicate values based on BeginOffset and EndOffset values, and change the names according to the duplicated values consider this,
The input i have is this

```
data = [
{
  "Text": "First",
  "Id": 1,
  "BeginOffset": 60,
  "EndOffset": 73,
  "Score": 0.5620501637458801,
  "Category": "Testing",
  "Type": "Name",
    
},
{
  "Text": "Second",
  "Id": 5,
  "BeginOffset": 60,
  "EndOffset": 73,
  "Score": 0.959932804107666,
  "Category": "Testing 2",
  "Type": "Name 2"
},
{
  "Text": "Third",
  "Id": 2,
  "BeginOffset": 85,
  "EndOffset": 94,
  "Score": 0.9013960361480713,
  "Category": "Testing 3",
  "Type": "Value"}]
```

And the output i want

```
data = [
{
  "Text": "First",
  "Id": 1,
  "BeginOffset": 60,
  "EndOffset": 73,
  "Score-1": 0.5620501637458801,
  "Category-1": "Testing",
  "Type-1": "Name",
  "Score-2": 0.959932804107666,
  "Category-2": "Testing 2",
  "Type-2": "Name 2"
    
},
{
  "Text": "Third",
  "Id": 2,
  "BeginOffset": 85,
  "EndOffset": 94,
  "Score": 0.9013960361480713,
  "Category": "Testing 3",
  "Type": "Value",
  
}]
```

You can see the second data has been merged with the first data cause they have the same BeginOffset and EndOffset same, so we merge them both into one single object with different name.

Can anyone help in this, Thanks in advance...

Comment: This seems inconsistent in the output. You have Score-1 & Score-2 but Category & Category-1. That aside, wouldn't it make more sense to keep the same key names but convert their values to a list?

Comment: I don't want to keep that as a list cause i need to keep track them separately, cause later i need to use in ML model so need to check category-1 and category-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this. There may be better ways:

```
data = [
    {
        "Text": "First",
        "Id": 1,
        "BeginOffset": 60,
        "EndOffset": 73,
        "Score": 0.5620501637458801,
        "Category": "Testing",
        "Type": "Name",

    },
    {
        "Text": "Second",
        "Id": 5,
        "BeginOffset": 60,
        "EndOffset": 73,
        "Score": 0.959932804107666,
        "Category": "Testing 2",
        "Type": "Name 2"
    },
    {
        "Text": "Third",
        "Id": 2,
        "BeginOffset": 85,
        "EndOffset": 94,
        "Score": 0.9013960361480713,
        "Category": "Testing 3",
        "Type": "Value"}
]

BO = 'BeginOffset'
EO = 'EndOffset'
SC = 'Score'
CA = 'Category'
TY = 'Type'
N = '_n'

output = []

def get_match(jdata, dc):
    for d in jdata:
        if d[BO] == dc[BO] and d[EO] == dc[EO]:
            return d

for d in data:
    d.setdefault(N, 0)
    if (dc := get_match(output, d)):
        if dc[N] == 0:
            for k in CA, SC, TY:
                dc[f'{k}-1'] = dc[k]
                del dc[k]
            dc[N] = 1   
        dc[N] += 1
        for k in CA, SC, TY:
            dc[f'{k}-{dc[N]}'] = d[k]
    else:
        output.append(d)

for d in output:
    del d[N]

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Text': 'First', 'Id': 1, 'BeginOffset': 60, 'EndOffset': 73, 'Category-1': 'Testing', 'Score-1': 0.5620501637458801, 'Type-1': 'Name', 'Category-2': 'Testing 2', 'Score-2': 0.959932804107666, 'Type-2': 'Name 2'}, {'Text': 'Third', 'Id': 2, 'BeginOffset': 85, 'EndOffset': 94, 'Score': 0.9013960361480713, 'Category': 'Testing 3', 'Type': 'Value'}]
```

Comment: Hey, just a one more question let's say in our json objects we have a key called ```Distance``` and if we get any repated values based on BeginOffset and EndOffset so we want to check the Distance also and only want to take the positive distance, how can i modify this code according to that condition? thanks in advance.

Comment: @iamhimanshu0 You will need to modify the *get_match()* function